# How to clear some forms fields on collapse

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form that includes a collapsing well with optional fields.  I'm trying to figure out how to clear those optional fields if they choose to toggle the well shut or hit the cancel button which also toggles the well shut.

```
    <form id="meeting">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="white" for="">Set Meeting Date &amp; Time</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" value="07/26/2017 09:05 pm" id="MeetingTime" name="MeetingTime" />
      </div>

      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-target="#offSiteMeeting" data-toggle="collapse" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off" aria-controls="offSiteMeeting">Offsite Meeting</button>


      <div class="collapse" id="offSiteMeeting">
        <div class="well">

            <a class="btn btn-default pull-right" href="" data-    toggle="collapse" data-target="#offSiteMeeting" aria-controls="offSiteMeeting">Cancel Offsite</a>

             <div class="form-group">
              <label class="" for="">Meeting Type</label>
              <select id="meetingType" name="meetingType" class="form-control">
                <option value="1">Meeting Type 1 </option>
                <option value="2">Meeting Type 2 </option>
                <option value="3">Meeting Type 3 </option>
              </select>
            </div><!-- close form-group -->


            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="" for="">Location Name</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" id="name" name="name" placeholder="ex. Jones Family Home" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="" for="">Address</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" id="address" name="address" placeholder="1234 Some Street City, State Zip"/>
            </div>

        </div><!-- close well -->
      </div><!-- close collapse -->

      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </div>          
    </form>
```

So the inputs I'd like to clear (in Form id="meeting") are

id=meetingType, id=name, id=address

when the well with id="offSiteMeeting" is collapsed

Here are the two buttons that collapse the well

```
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-target="#offSiteMeeting" data-toggle="collapse" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off" aria-controls="offSiteMeeting">Offsite Meeting</button>

     <a class="btn btn-default pull-right" href="" data-toggle="collapse"    data-target="#offSiteMeeting" aria-controls="offSiteMeeting">Cancel Offsite</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this parameter to your buttons

```
onclick="function () { document.getElementById('meetingType').value = ''; document.getElementById('name').value = ''; document.getElementById('address').value = '';}"
```

or if you are into jquery

```
onclick="function () { $('#meetingType').val(''); $('#name').val(''); $('#address').val(''); }"
```